# How to pass a java object to HTTP Post parameters

Tags: java, http-post

I want to pass a java object to HTTP POST parameters using `java.net.*`? The Object contains multiple parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(REQUEST_URL);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
//put here in nameValuePairs request parameters

UrlEncodedFormEntity form;
form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8");
form.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
httppost.setEntity(form);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```